# Designing an algorithm with tasks in openmp

Tags: c++, multithreading, task, gpu, openmp

I currently have a code which does work on a large data set, generating an array at the end. This is array has to then be added into a global buffer, and this all happens inside a loop. Eg.

```
for(i=0;i<10000;i++)
{   <1. do some processing, generate a 1M-sized array>
    <2. update this array into global buffer>
}
```

The task 1 happens on the GPU, and I want the 2nd part to happen parallely on CPU, i.e. where 1 thread controls the GPU for task 1, and all other threads do task 2 when 1 buffer is ready for processing. For a basic case, how can I do this with one copy of a buffer (i.e. one on GPU-side and one on CPU-side to receive GPU copy)?

Comment: Actually I need both things, making step 1 happen in parallel with step 2, and multithread step 2 also, if possible. To parallelize b/w step 1 and 2, I need some synchronization, so that step 2 knows that a new buffer is generated for it to work on, and step 1 knows when to overwrite the old buffer. What step 2 does is go through the 1M-sized array element by element, and if it meets some conditions, do some calculations to find the appropriate location in the global buffer array where I have to add it in, and then I go add it.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is have a producer-consumer set of tasks such that step 1 produces a buffer, and step 2 consumes that buffer while incorporating the results to your global array.

Something like (inside the usual `parallel`+`single`):

```
const int buffer_size = 100000;
type global[buffer_size];
type buffer[2][buffer_size];

for(int i=0;i<10000;i++)
{
    type *buf[buffer_size] = buffer[i % 2];
    #pragma omp task depend(out: [buffer_size]buf)
    {
        <1. write to buf>
    }

    #pragma omp task depend(in: [buffer_size]buf) depend(inout: [buffer_size]global)
    {
        <2. update global using buf>
    }
}
```

This allows to overlap step 2 with step 1, with one iteration of "lag", that is step 1 of iteration i=1 will run concurrently to iteration i=0 of step 2.
You will need one buffer per overlapping iteration, so that each simultaneous operation can happen independently of one another.

Now the semantics of buf (`in`/`out`) are simple, as they are simple procuder-consumer relations. For the global, you need `inout`, as you update the buffer in-place: get the current array (`in`) and assign new values to it (`out`). This means all the tasks of step 2 will be serialized due to this dependency, meaning that at most 2 iterations can be overlapped (and that there is no point in using more than 2 buffers).

This is a limitation of current OpenMP (4.5) tasks, though [a proposal for task reductions](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-319-24595-9_14) exists that would resolve this. An alternative way would be to declare global as `shared`, in which case you need to modify it using atomic operations.

You may use a `target` clause to execute task 1 on the GPU. Make sure that the data from the offloaded device (i.e. the GPU) is copied to the CPU. Inside the task of step 2 you can then parallelize the step 2 itself, using either a parallel for construct, or tasks again.